# friend class cannot be recognized

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

i want to make "func" class as the friend of "node" class. but unfortunately functions in func class cannot access private members of node class.for example in function "expand" i receive an error which stats that n is undefined.since i'm new to programming, would u plz tell me what the problem is?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#define max 9 //we use a const 

class node
{
private:
    int n[max];
    friend class func;
};

class func
{
public:
    bool isgoal(int);
    bool isvalid(int);
    void expand();
};
```

expand function:

```
void func::expand()
{ 
    for(int i=0;i<=8;i++)
    {
        n[i]=0;
    }
}
```

Another problem is that when i want to make a copy of class "node" in order to copy the members of array n into it with this code:

```
    void func::expand()
    { 
        node b=n;
}
```

it says that "constructor cannot convert from int[9] to node

how can I copy the members of n into a temp array in this program?

Comment: `void node::expand` Class `node` doesn't have a member named `expand`

Comment: `n` is a non-static data member of `node`. You need an instance of `node` on which to access this member.

Comment: but i have defined it in class node and since node and func are friends, expand should access to it.

Comment: Suppose you have `node a, b;` - two instances of `node`. Imagine `n[i]=0` worked just like that. Which object would it modify - `a.n`, `b.n`, some other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but unfortunately functions in func class cannot access private
>   members of node class

Friend class func can can indeed access private members of an instance of node.  But your func methods have been provided no information about which node instance they might access.

You might change

```
bool isgoal(int);
```

to

```
bool isgoal(int, node*);

bool isgoal(int, node&);
```

or provide a node* instance as part of class func, which must be initialized.

Comment: In other words, imagine you have 500 instances of node, and 5 instances of func.  Your code needs to inform the compiler which node instance can be accessed by which specific func instance.